# Use .so File for ARM in java project

Tags: java, unix, arm, shared-libraries

I have a `.so` file which contains a method I want to use in my java program.
I tried to load it via `System.load("/usr/lib/file.so");`

but then I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/file.so: /usr/lib/file.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (Possible cause: can't load ARM-bit .so on a IA 32-bit platform)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1935)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1860)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1821)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:792)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1059)
        at t1.<clinit>(t1.java:7)
```

How can I make it work or what system do I need to make it work?

Comment: Are you trying to load an arm so on an x86 machine?

Comment: my processor is intel 64bit but I tried it on x86 linux